# How to check the authentication token created or not and keep it in cookie

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jpa, cxf

My Requirement is when user logs , a REST web service has to send a cookie which contains userid and later he has to create a authentication token and save it in database store and has to keep the token in a cookie. Later if he logs in again a web service has to check whether the token was already created or not , if created get it from db or create new token. can u please check and let me know whether authentication token was created securely AND my question was how to check whether token was created earlier or not and how to keep in cookie

```
private static byte[] getSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    secureRandom.nextBytes(salt);
    return salt;
}

public static String getHashWithSalt(String userid) {
    String token = null;
    try {
        MessageDigest msgDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] salt = getSalt();
        msgDigest.reset();
        msgDigest.update(salt);
        msgDigest.update(userid.getBytes());
        byte byteData[] = msgDigest.digest();
        System.out.println("msgDigest value --> " + byteData.toString());
        token = toHexString(byteData);
        System.out.println("token --> " + token);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return token;
}

// This method converts the byte Array to Hexa String format
private static String toHexString(byte[] byteData) {
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & byteData[i]);
        hexString.append(hex);
    }
    return hexString.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question properly:

> how to check whether token was created earlier

If you are storing the token in a DB, then when you receive the token from the cookie, you can validate it against values in the DB.  If the token received in the cookie already exists in the DB, then it has already been created.

As for how to keep it in the cookie, when you first create the cookie, just set the appropriate expiry date.  If MaxAge is set to a negative value, then the cookie will be automatically deleted once the browser session is closed.